# Where clause - pass in as a var?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I wish to pass in a where clause dynamically to a query:

```
User::where('published', '=', '1')->get();
```

When I try and pass in an array, it errors:

```
$where = ['published', '=', '1'];
User::where($where)->get();
```

How can I pass in params stored in a var?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. If for some reason you need something similar but working, try this instead:

```
$where = ['published', '1'];
User::where($where[0], $where[1])->get();
```

But much better way is to use [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes):

```
User::published()->get();
```

And in `User` model:

```
public function scopePublished($query)
{
    return $query->where('published', 1);
}
```

Comment: The scope wouldn't be a better way, as I would have to scope every potential where clause that could be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$attributes = [
                    [
                      'column' =>   'published',
                      'condition' =>   '=',
                      'value' =>  '1'
                    ],
                    [
                      'column' =>   'first_name',
                      'condition' =>   '=',
                      'value' =>  'John' 
                    ],
            ];


 $getUser = User::where(function($query) use($attributes){
                   foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
                   $query->where($value['column'],$value['condition'],$value['value']);
                            }
                        })->get();
```

Comment: Wouldnt work as sometimes you would not want to specify condition

Answer (score 0):

You could do a (partly) raw query and pass in the SQL statement as a string. Something like this:

```
$where = "'published' = '1'";
User::whereRaw($where)->get();
```

Or like this:

```
$where = "'published' = :published";
$published = 1;
User::whereRaw($where, compact('published'))->get();
```